# How to collect data via WFS and Popup

Tags: openlayers-2, editing, fields-attributes, popup

I have a map with a WFS-Layer and I am able to add Polygons to my data stored in a PostGIS-database, served with GeoServer (OpenLayers, GeoServer 2.1.4, PostGIS 2.0 for PostgreSQL 9.1).)

How can I add a description to the polygon? E.g., after drawing a polygon I want to specify the crop that are grown there, i.e. insert information into the Postgis-table-column "crop".

I found this example:

http://gis.ibbeck.de/ginfo/apps/OLExamples/OL26/examples/styles_unique_with_group_wfs.html.

The Popup type "edit name and description" would be perfect for my means, unfortunately I can't work out how it works as I have a really hard time understanding its code, greenhorn that I am...

- How is it done?
- Or is there an easier example/ way of how to use a popup to edit your attributes?

---

Here's my WFS-Layer and the tools used so far. The desired column to edit/add Information in the postgis-table "test" is "crop".

```
function init() {
Save-strategy
var saveStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Save();

//empty map, bounds are test-layer bounds (EPSG:32647)  
map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: "map",
    allOverlays: true,
    maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(
    653237.69439077,1519879.063165,655229.57939001,1520825.6733868
    )
    });

//WFS-Layer Test= editable data
var test = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Editable Features", {
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed(), saveStrategy],    
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
    url: "http://..../wfs",
    featurePrefix: 'testkf',
    featureNS: "http://.../testkf",
    extractAttributes: true,
    featureType: "test",
    geometryName: "geom",
    })
});

map.addLayer(test);

//Toolbar:
    var panel = new OpenLayers.Control.Panel(
    {'displayClass': 'customEditingToolbar'}
    );

    var draw = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(
    test, OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon,
    {
    title: "Draw Feature",
    displayClass: "olControlDrawFeaturePolygon",
    multi: true
    });

    var save = new OpenLayers.Control.Button({
    title: "Save Changes",
    trigger: function() {
    if(edit.feature) {
    edit.selectControl.unselectAll();
    }
    saveStrategy.save();
    },
    displayClass: "olControlSaveFeatures"
    });


panel.addControls([save, draw]);
map.addControl(panel);  
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
map.zoomToMaxExtent();
}
```

EDIT:

So nobody knows anything about this topic or is there another problem with my question? I found another example, however, this is way too complex for me to understand yet: http://dev4.mapgears.com/bdga/bdgaWFS-T.html

This is exactly what I am looking for. Can anyone break it down to me what the steps are to achieve this?

Or is there any way to improve my question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To all the people who are looking for a way to collect data via Popup as asked in my question, this is how I solved it (same script as in question except the **added popup-function and the tool "select"**):

```
function init() {
Save-strategy
var saveStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Save();

//empty map, bounds are test-layer bounds (EPSG:32647)  
map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: "map",
    allOverlays: true,
    maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(
    653237.69439077,1519879.063165,655229.57939001,1520825.6733868
    )
    });

//WFS-Layer Test= editable data
var test = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Editable Features", {
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed(), saveStrategy],    
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
    url: "http://..../wfs",
    featurePrefix: 'testkf',
    featureNS: "http://.../testkf",
    extractAttributes: true,
    featureType: "test",
    geometryName: "geom",
    })
});

map.addLayer(test);

//add Popup
        var select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(test);
            map.addControl(select);
            select.activate();

        function onPopupClose(evt) {
            selectControl.unselect(selectedFeature);
        }

        <!-- crucial part is form within popup. careful with linebreaks-->  
        test.events.on({
            featureselected: function(event) {
                var feature = event.feature;
                feature.popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud
                ("pop",
                feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
                null,
                '<form action="http://.../myphp.php" method="post" target="new">'+                  
                '<p><div class="label"> entry by:</div> <input name="entryname" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30"  value="'+feature.attributes.entryname+'" ></p><br>'+
                '<input type="submit" name="schreiben" value="Submit" onClick="window.location.reload()"></form>',
                null,
                true 
                );
             map.addPopup(feature.popup);  
            },

            <!-- destroy popup when feature is no longer selected. Prevents showing 2 Popups at the same time-->
            featureunselected: function(event) {
                var feature = event.feature;
                map.removePopup(feature.popup);
                feature.popup.destroy();
                feature.popup = null;
            }
        });

//Toolbar:
    var panel = new OpenLayers.Control.Panel(
    {'displayClass': 'customEditingToolbar'}
    );

    var select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(test, {
    title: "Select Field",
    displayClass: "olControlSelectFeature"
    });

    var draw = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(
    test, OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon,
    {
    title: "Draw Feature",
    displayClass: "olControlDrawFeaturePolygon",
    multi: true
    });

    var save = new OpenLayers.Control.Button({
    title: "Save Changes",
    trigger: function() {
    if(edit.feature) {
    edit.selectControl.unselectAll();
    }
    saveStrategy.save();
    },
    displayClass: "olControlSaveFeatures"
    });


panel.addControls([save, draw, select]);
map.addControl(panel);  
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
map.zoomToMaxExtent();
}
```

For the form within the popup, a separate php-script is needed. Here, the crucial part is:

```
$res = pg_query ("UPDATE $tabelle SET entryname = '".pg_escape_string ($entryname)."' WHERE gid = '$gid'");
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Cat, I have tried your solution for editing attributes via popup, but it didn't work for me. Can you write whole code for "myphp.php" script, please? I suppose that problem is here. I am working on similar web map, everything works fine (WFS-draw,modify,delete, save....) but the only thing I can't implement is editing attributes via popup. Any other solution from others is also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much detail to go into, but the second link you give looks like a good place to start.

First, you need to register some of the editing events for your test layer.

e.g.
olWFSRoads.events.register("afterfeaturemodified",'', onRoadModificationEnd);)

This will call the onRoadModificationEnd method once a user finishes editing a feature for this layer.  In this method you need to display the popup where the user can enter the details.  In the example this method is in a file called bdgaRoads.js.

Then in the save button of the popup you can actually save the feature and any attributes.

I'm a bit pushed for time at the minute but hopefully this should at least send you in the right direction.  Let me know if you need more detail on anything.

Comment: hi, thanks very much for answering! I'm afraid, however, this does not help me much.. I took a good long look on the code and tried to reconstruct what is being done, and although the second example is much more organised than the first one, I'm too clueless to even understand what all the different functions/ids/etc. stand for. I know it's too much to ask for, but at the moment I feel that only an answer with the code would help me...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you still care about this question, but this might be helpful for somebody.You can see the source code by pressing crtl + u. Hope this helps.